app shows in browser only non readable characters
I have here an web application which I don't have the source files for. I know the application was created with WebForms. The application works, mostly. I have copied its files on another computer to try some investigation. I use IIS. The problem is that the browser shows only non-readable characters, nothing else, no controls. Like when you open a binary file with a text editor.
�*ƨ,�ĕ\���Hڰ;���

Is the same in Chrome, Firefox or Edge. The development tools in browser shows that also the elements, the html part, has the same problem. The Source tab shows text not scrambled. Needless to say that my browsers are ok, they don't exhibit such behavior for anything else, just for that application. If open the files of the server with a text editor, they are human readable. I mean the Web.config, the few cs, aspx etc. files which are part of the server because, as I said, I don't have all the sources. If I go to Network tab in development tools in browser, I see in Preview and Response also unreadable characters.




Try changing your browsers encoding. settings->tools->encoding. So, this suggest's the site (or your computer) has different language settings then the site - a bit of a guess on my part, but try changing the encoding on one of your browsers.  And if you do see all of the say Default.aspx, and a corresponding Default.cs.aspx, then you may well have all of the source code files. If you don't see a corresponding file for each .aspx page, then you don't have the source code files.
